# Prepend, append <li> in Jquery Uploader

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am using jQueryUI, and jQuery BlueImp File Uploader. Using the uploader, I would like to create drag and droppable UI objects with jQuery UI.

In order to do this however, I need to append a `<li>` and `</li>` tag to the front and back of the file that is displayed. For example, in the below script I am using the uploader to display thumbnails of each of the images uploaded.

How can I prepend `li` and append `/li`  to each image that is being displayed?

```
<script>
/*jslint unparam: true, regexp: true */
/*global window, $ */
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
    var url = window.location.hostname === '' ?
                '' : 'server/php/',
        uploadButton = $('<button/>')
           // .addClass('btn')
            .prop('disabled', true)
          //  .text('Processing...')
           .on('click', function () {
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data();
                $this
                    .off('click')
                    .text('Abort')
                    .on('click', function () {
                        $this.remove();
                        data.abort();
                    });
                data.submit().always(function () {
                    $this.remove();
                });
            });
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        autoUpload: true,
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|mp4)$/i,
        maxFileSize: 50000000, // 5 MB
        // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
        // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
        // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
        disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
            .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
        previewMaxWidth: 100,
        previewMaxHeight: 100,
        previewCrop: true
    }).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
        data.context = $('<div/>').appendTo('#files');
        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
            var node = $('<p/>')
                    //.append($('<span/>').text(file.name));
            if (!index) {
                node
                    .append('')
                  //  .append(uploadButton.clone(true).data(data));
            }
            node.appendTo(data.context);
        });
    }).on('fileuploadprocessalways', function (e, data) {
        var index = data.index,
            file = data.files[index],
            node = $(data.context.children()[index]);
        if (file.preview) {
            node
                .prepend('')
                .prepend(file.preview);
        }
        if (file.error) {
            node
                .append('<br>')
                .append(file.error);
        }
        if (index + 1 === data.files.length) {
            data.context.find('button')
              //  .text('Upload2')
                .prop('disabled', !!data.files.error);
        }
    }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('#progress .bar').css(
            'width',
            progress + '%'
        );
    }).on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
         $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
        //    var link = $('<a>')
               // .attr('target', '_blank')
             //   .prop('href', file.url);
            $(data.context.children()[index])
              //  .wrap(link);
        });
    }).on('fileuploadfail', function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
            var error = $('<span/>').text(file.error);
            $(data.context.children()[index])
                .append('<br>')
                .append(error);
        });
    }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
        .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
});
</script>
```

Comment: `$('selector').wrap('<li/>');`

Comment: i got confused from your question and that long code, can you please describe: what you get now as an output and what your goal output?

Comment: My output now is just an <img> with the file that they uploaded. What happens is a <img> is created for each upload. I want to wrap those in a li

Comment: are you using the template scripts provided by blueimp, you can modify the markup there? if you need to modify the code you posted, i would start by logging `file.preview` in the `fileuploadprocessalways` handler, I believe there's where you should append/prepend the li markup

Comment: @koala_dev I did not know you could modify those in such a way - What do you mean by logging? I'm not familiar with that term besides logging errors.

Comment: What version of the fileupload plugin did you implement? Basic, Basic Plus, Basic Plus UI? the UI version has a couple of template script tags with `id="template-upload"` and `id="template-download"` where the markup for the file list is located. By logging I meant using `console.log(file.preview);` this will output the value of the variable in the console (which you can access by pressing Ctrl+Shift+J). Finally do you really need to modify the markup to create your draggable items? you can use any selector to initialize the draggable/droppable widget, i.e: `$('img').draggable();`

Comment: @koala_dev I used Basic Plus, but I can use Basic Plus UI. My main thought behind making them list objects, was so that I could output their order when they click a "submit" button. My goal is to let them upload, drag and rearrange, and then hit submit to give me a output of the order they drug them in.